# Magic stone (Bonus action) with Eldritch Blast (cantrip 1 action)

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Ok so now for a question that I have can I use Magic Stone and then Eldritch Blast, or is the normal way as I think it is, is only Eldritch Blast and then Magic Stone?

Answer (score 3):

You chose your answer too swiftly to the last question as I addressed this question in my answer to your first question; but your answer is:

**Yes**, because the rules do not state there must be an order to the 1 spell + 1 action cantrip rule, and because a cantrip is a spell of level 0 and fulfills the requirements; you CAN cast Magic Stone as a bonus action cantrip and then follow it up with a single action cantrip of Eldritch Blast.

This does not break the rules of casting a bonus action spell (spells can be spells of level 1 or higher as well as cantrips) , then only being able to cast a cantrip of 1 action.  You are still following the rules, no matter what order you follow them in.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the broader question. During your turn you get:

- 1 move
- 1 action
- 1 bonus action if you qualify
- 1 reaction (which you could take on someone else's turn too)

**You can take them in any order.** Further, you can break your move up around the action(s) if you like. Further further, if you take the Attack action and that gives you more than one attack you can move and insert your bonus action in between the attacks.

Your question is a subset of this so, yes, you can do it.